# MySQL - Order of check in unique constraints

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I have a table with 4 uniques columns `(Id, Email, Name, FacebookId)`. Id is auto incremented so not really relevant for the question. I'd like to know if there is a way to specify the priority for the unique fields.

For instance I insert `(test@test.com, Test, 123456)`. Then I try to insert the same data, this trigger a constraint violation on Email column. Is there a way to trigger this violation on FacebookId column first ?

I tried to reorder the column in phpMyAdmin, also tried to remove and add in different order the unique constraints but nothing worked. Is this possible at all ?

Comment: it is not about order it is about unique values. post your  `CREATE TABLE` statement

Comment: Your INSERT does not have to be in left to right order...

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...I found this at mysql.com, would this help?

> MySQL supports an IGNORE keyword for INSERT, UPDATE, and so forth. If
>   you use it, MySQL ignores primary-key or unique-key violations and
>   continues processing with the next row.

(source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html)

Here's their section on using IGNORE with INSERT, and at the top is an example I think may really be helpful - it looks like they're prioritizing things - check it out! I hope this helps: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html

Do you wish for SQL to worry only about FacebookId, or do you just want it to verify FacebookId isn't a duplicate FIRST, and then move on and verify that other columns' data isn't duped also (in this case probably just email since multiple people can have the same spelling of a name), such as "First make sure FacebookId is unique, next make sure that Email is unique", etc?